# Is there always exist counterexamples for known convergence tests?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I'm learning about convergence tests and I have a question about it - Does there exists some converging positive sequence which is inconclusive for every known tests? I only consider positive sequences.

To get rid of tests such as Kummer's test which handles on the choice of some sequence $p_n$, for here I define convergence tests as : Let $f:R^k→R$ and $ρ=lim_{n→∞}f(a_{n+1},…,a_{n+k})$, then the convergence is determined by $\rho$. The examples of such test are  Ratio test, Raabe test, Bertrand test. Does anyone know that if there exists the "ultimate" test, or there is always a counterexample for such tests defined above?

So far I have a strong feeling that there should always exist such a counterexample - which is equivalent with the nonexistence of such convergence test. Perhaps we can start with the case $k=2$.

Comment: [Comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)?)

Comment: @above it includes terms not from the original sequence so it doesn't satisfy the definition.

Comment: Each test gives a sufficient critetrion for convergence, but an "ultimate" test would be an *equivalent characterization* of convergence, i.e some reformulation of the definition. I doubt that this would be useful, a test should be *easily applicable* which conflicts with being universal.

Comment: Long story short, for every sequence there is a "stronger" test (one that solves the sequence), and for every test there is a "stronger" sequence (one that is inconclusive for the test). There is no ultimate limit to this ladder.

Comment: I think Section 4.7 (pp. 142-151) of Marion Scheepers's survey [*Gaps in* $\left(^{\omega}{\omega}, \prec \right)$](https://math.boisestate.edu/~marion/research/order/gaps.pdf) gives a high-powered proof that the answer is YES for most any reasonable meaning of "convergence test".

Comment: @Ivan Neretin Is there some reference of it?

Comment: @Paul Frost But tests do not need equivalence. So it can be a weaker argument different from an equivalent characterization

Comment: @Hypernova What exactly do we mean by "convergence is determined by $\rho$"? Do we mean "if $\rho\in A$ then the series is convergent", where $A$ is some fixed subset of $\mathbb{R}$? Or "$\rho\in A$ if and only if the series is convergent"? Or something entirely different?

Comment: @freakish the first one. if $\rho \in A$ then the series is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an answer to a related problem that might give some insight: there doesn’t exist any algorithm that can decide if a given computable series converges.

To prove this, consider an enumeration $T_1,T_2,\ldots$ of all Turing machines, and define $x_n(k)$ to be $1$ if $T_n$ doesn’t halt after $k$ steps, and $0$ otherwise. Notice that this function is computable. But if an algorithm could determine if any of these series $x_n(1),x_n(2),\ldots$ converged, this would solve the halting problem, which is impossible. So no such algorithm exists.

Comment: Are the standard  tests (e.g. the root test for series) able to decide whether a  given computable series converges?

Comment: Also this answer at most says that there is no such computable function $f$, not that such $f$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't really answer the question.  The convergence of the series $\sum_n x_n(k)$ could in principle be decided by e.g. a limit comparison test, it's just that we have no way of evaluating the limits.

Comment: The convergence of any one of the given series might be able to be established. But what I’m proving is that no algorithm can prove the convergence of all of them. So, as a consequence, there are always sequences for which a test is inconclusive.

Comment: The test isn't really inconclusive, it's just that the result of the test can't be computed.

Comment: @RobertIsrael If the result of the test can’t always be computed, then it wasn’t the “ultimate test” to begin with.

Comment: @freakish If you can’t always establish convergence for computable functions, how could you do it for general functions? How would you even be able to test an uncomputable function?

Comment: No, my bad, I answered a slightly different question. I’m still leaving this answer as insight.

Comment: *How would you even be able to test an uncomputable function?* --- Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of uncomputable functions. Then $\sum 2^{-n}\arctan (|f_n|)$ is a series, each term of which is an uncomputable function, such that its convergence is easily determined.